# Average velocity of fluid flow

Tags: average, fluid-dynamics

Washburn equation for fluid flow in horizontal capillary is given by :
$\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{γR}{4µL}$

Find the time dependencies of length of travel, $L(T)$ and average velocity.

I can find the first part by integrating the Washburn eqn but I am a little confused as to how to find the average velocity as a function of t.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask this in the physics stack exchange?

Comment: Nevertheless, I came up with the best answer I could. Tell me if this helped.

Comment: You have the Washburn equation wrong. $L^2 = \frac{γRt}{4µ}$. This gives distance from starting point and starting time. So at t=0, then L=0.

Comment: If you integrate the differential equation,you get your form of the Washburn eqn.

Comment: Velocity of what? What is the difference between $\dot{L}$ and $v$?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the average velocity is equal to
$$\frac{\Delta L}{\Delta t}=\frac{L_2-L_1}{t_2-t_1}$$
Which can be found by integrating the velocity over a certain interval and dividing it by the length of that interval.

The expression $\frac{dL}{dt}$ is equal to the instantaneous velocity, so integrating the function gives
$$L(t) = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma Rt}{2\mu}}$$

and so the average velocity from $t=a$ to $t=b$ is

$$\frac{L(b)-L(a)}{b-a}
= \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\gamma Rb}{2\mu}}-\sqrt{\frac{\gamma Ra}{2\mu}}}{b-a}
=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma R}{2\mu}}\frac{\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}}{b-a}$$

Comment: Thanks. That clears it up a bit. But a and b are not given quantities in the question. 
I will ask in the physics stack forum. :)